# How to calculate normalized euclidean distance on two vectors?

Tags: matlab, euclidean-distance

Let's say I have the following two vectors:

```
x = [(10-1).*rand(7,1) + 1; randi(10,1,1)];
y = [(10-1).*rand(7,1) + 1; randi(10,1,1)];
```

The first seven elements are continuous values in the range [1,10]. The last element is an integer in the range [1,10].

Now I would like to compute the euclidean distance between x and y. I think the integer element is a problem because all other elements can get very close but the integer element has always spacings of ones. So there is a bias towards the integer element.

How can I calculate something like a normalized euclidean distance on it?

Comment: related: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/136232/definition-of-normalized-euclidean-distance

Answer (score 10, accepted):

According to [Wolfram Alpha](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NormalizedSquaredEuclideanDistance.html), and [the following answer from cross validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/136232/definition-of-normalized-euclidean-distance), the normalized Eucledean distance is defined by:

[image]

You can calculate it with MATLAB by using:

```
0.5*(std(x-y)^2) / (std(x)^2+std(y)^2)
```

Alternatively, you can use:

```
0.5*((norm((x-mean(x))-(y-mean(y)))^2)/(norm(x-mean(x))^2+norm(y-mean(y))^2))
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So I have to normalize each dimension but I have only two data points, i.e. I have two values for each dimension. Is this not a bit less for using the standard deviation (or mean)?

Comment: By the way, could I also use zscore, i.e. subtracting the mean and dividing by the standard deviation, and then just using normal Euclidean distance?

Comment: Regarding to your first comment - this definition is well defined with vectors in R^2 as well). About the second one - it may also work, I will think about it and get back to you

Comment: where does that equation come from?

Answer (score 2):

I would rather normalise x and y before calculating the distance and then vanilla Euclidean would suffice.

In your example

```
x_norm = (x -1) / 9;          % normalised x
y_norm = (y -1) / 9;          % normalised y
dist = norm(x_norm - y_norm); % Euclidean distance between normalised x, y
```

However, I am not sure about whether having an integer element contributes to some sort of bias but we have already gotten kind of off-topic for stack overflow :)

Comment: Thanks. How did you standardize (why subtracting 1 and dividing by 9)? To which stackexchange would this toppic better match?

Comment: I guess cross-validated would be a better match for this topic. In order to normalise say  x  in the [0,1] interval you need to do (x - min(x))/(max(x) - min(x)).

Answer (score 1):

From [Euclidean Distance - raw, normalized and double‐scaled coefficients](https://www.pbarrett.net/techpapers/euclid.pdf)

> **SYSTAT**, **Primer 5**, and **SPSS** provide Normalization options for the data so as to permit an investigator to compute a distance
>   coefficient which is essentially “scale free”.  **Systat 10.2**’s
>   normalised Euclidean distance produces its “normalisation” by dividing
>   each squared discrepancy between attributes or persons by the total
>   number of squared discrepancies (or sample size).

[image: normalised Euclidean distance]

> Frankly, I can see little point in this standardization – as the final
>   coefficient still remains scale‐sensitive. That is, it is impossible
>   to know whether the value indicates high or low dissimilarity from the
>   coefficient value alone